# How to run .exe file using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, process

i want to run .exe file from local server.
here is below code :

```
   String cmds = "C:\\IBM\\Abhishek\\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";
 try {
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
     System.out.println("process "+p);
     p.waitFor();

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line = reader.readLine();
     System.out.println("Line---"+line);
     while (line != null) {
       System.out.println("File---"+line);
       line = reader.readLine();
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" Sample Exception :"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here output is getting  :

```
Sample Exception :Cannot run program "C:\IBM\Abhishek\Notepad++": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.
```

Please suggest,

Comment: You want to run `Notepad++` from a Servlet? **Why?**

Comment: I want to open through Servlet,is that possible?

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra you can even open it by double clicking on the .exe file. why would you even want something like this?

Comment: for example, i want to try on notepad.otherwise  why  should i open? i have some other .exe file.

Answer (score 4):

The error message says `CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.`
which implies your Java servlet's process doesn't have permissions to execute that program.

The cause, I think, is that you are missing an `\\` in front of `notepad++.exe`. You need to escape all of the backslashes.

```
   "C:\\IBM\\Abhishek\\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
-> "C:\\IBM\\Abhishek\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's plain to see in the error that it's trying to run a folder. "C:\IBM\Abhishek\Notepad++" in stead of "C:\IBM\Abhishek\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

Comment: Is it still producing the same exception? Or a different one?

Comment: If it's a different exception, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 means one of on the following reasons. Either the File is not accessible or the File is not executable.

Comment: Or option three, [the Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) won't allow it.